# Why do tennis players blow on their fingers after a point?

Tags: tennis

It seems common these days for tennis players to blow on their fingertips after winning a point. I've noticed it particularly with the server: they'll do an arm pump with clenched fist then open the fist and blow on their fingers.

If it were just one player I'd consider it superstition but at this year's Wimbledon tournament it seems very common.

Is there a known reason behind this?

Comment: I do it (in badminton, but close enough) to try to get sweat off my fingers and make them less slippery for holding the racket without having to go for a towel. Don’t know if that’s why the pros do it as well, but it would make sense if it is.